# Using Beamer router with flutter, the url changes but the navigation doesn't happen

Tags: dart, flutter-web, flutter-beamer

I am trying to use beamer for navigation in my flutter web app. It seems to be partially working, but I am encountering some issues.

The first page is the sign in page, and when I sign in, after the authentication, the nagvigator is supposed to navigate to the home page. When I sign in, and authentication is successful, I can see the url change in the browser, however, the page stays the same. The page changes if I refresh the page from the browser.

Here is related code:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final routerDelegate = BeamerDelegate(
      locationBuilder: RoutesLocationBuilder(
        routes: {
          '/': (context, state, data){
            return const BeamPage(
                title: 'Welcome to Space Shuttle Parking',
                child: SplashScreenDesktop()
            );
          },
          '/sign_in': (context, state, data){
            return const BeamPage(
                title: 'Sign in to your account',
                child: SigninPage()
            );
          },
          '/sign_up': (context, state, data){
            return const BeamPage(
                title: 'Create a new account',
                child: SigninPage()
            );
          },
          '/main/:page': (context, state, data){
            final page = state.pathParameters['page']!;
            return BeamPage(
              title: page.capitalizeFirst,
              child: LandingPage(page: page, extra: '',)
            );
          },
          '/main/:page/:extra': (context, state, data){
            final page = state.pathParameters['page']!;
            final extra = state.pathParameters['extra']!;
            return BeamPage(
              title: page.capitalizeFirst,
              child: LandingPage(page: page, extra: extra,)
            );
          }
        }
      )
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    //SpaceShuttleRouter.setupRouter();
    super.initState();
  }
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: BeamerParser(),
      routerDelegate: routerDelegate,
      title: 'Space Shuttle Parking - Booking Manager',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: 'Assistant'
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is where  I am signing in and navigating:

```
AuthController().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password, () {
  Fluttertoast.showToast(
    msg: 'Please wait'
  );
  Beamer.of(context).beamToNamed('/main/home');

},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be lacking page keys, without them Navigator doesn't replace the current beam page.

Example for your case:

```dart
'/sign_up': (context, state, data){
  return const BeamPage(
    key: ValueKey("sign_up"),
    title: 'Create a new account',
    child: SigninPage()
  );
},
```

https://pub.dev/packages/beamer#page-keys

> ### Page Keys
>
> When we beam somewhere, we are putting a new list of pages into
> `Navigator.pages`. Now the `Navigator` has to decide on the transition
> between the old list of pages and the new list of pages.
>
> In order to know which pages changed and which pages stayed the same,
> `Navigator` looks at the pages' `key`s. If the `key`s of 2 pages that
> are compared are equal (important here: `null` == `null`), `Navigator`
> treats them as the same page and does not rebuild nor replace that
> page.
>
> One should always set a `BeamPage.key` (most likely a
> [ValueKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueKey-class.html)).
> If `key`s are not set, after beaming somewhere via e.g.
> `Beamer.of(context).beamToNamed('/somewhere')`, no change will happen
> in the UI. The *new* `BeamPage` doesn't build since `Navigator` thinks
> it is the same as the already displayed one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74587959/how-to-use-beamer-navigator-in-a-flutter-web-app please.